# Detecting loss of keyboard focus in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, focus

I have a Silverlight game controlled by the keyboard, and I want it to go into pause when it loses the keyboard focus (e.g. the user clicks on another part of the hosting webpage, or moves to another browser tab).

I used to do this in Silverlight 1.1 by subscribing to the LostFocus event on my RootVisual UserControl, but in the last two versions of Silverlight, I have found this event seems to fire unexpectedly shortly after clicking a button in my application (in Silverlight 2 it fired once, in Silverlight 3 twice!).

Is there a way in javascript on the hosting page, or within Silverlight to detect loss of focus more reliably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem. The RoutedEventArgs property on the LostFocus event has an OriginalSource property which allows me to ignore any LostFocus events that come from children of the RootVisual.

```
    void Page_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource == this)
        {
            Pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? In my experience, when a child has focus and the focus is transfered outside of both the parent and the child, you never get a LostFocus with OriginalSource == parent.

I don't bother listening for LostFocus.  I do everything in GotFocus.

Comment: I guess its possible that there are some scenarios in which this isn't reliable, but for my game it works fine. Would be a nice update to Silverlight to have a global event you can subscribe to at the application level.